# Linear Transforms,their sums, and their ranks

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ and $S$ be linear transforms from a vector space $V$ to $W$.

Prove that

i) $\left( T+S\right)(V)\subseteq T(V) + S(V)$

ii)If $W$ is finite dimensional, then $\text{rank}(T+S)\le \text{rank}(T) + \text{rank}(S$)

Answer (score 1):

The first question is just a matter of unravelling definitions.  Start by writing precisely what $(T+S)(V)$ means and keep in mind what you're trying to show (namely, that each vector in the set $(T+S)(V)$ also lies in the set $(T(V) + S(V))$.  For example, you might start by considering a general vector $v \in V$. (Why is this sufficient?)

The second part should be a corollary of the first. Recall how the rank of a linear operator is defined, and use the fact that for nonnegative finite numbers $a$ and $b$ we have $a+b \ge \max(a,b)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some guidelines:

i) Fix arbitrary $v\in V$.  Now show that $(T+S)(v)$ can be written as $u_1+u_2$ where $u_1\in T(V)$ and $u_2\in S(V)$, showing that $v\in T(V)+S(V)$

ii) By definition $\operatorname{rank}(T+S) = \dim ((T+S)(V))$.  So, putting $\dim$ on both sides of what you have on (i), you should get what you want (noting that $\dim(V+W)\leq \dim(V)+\dim(W)$; do you see why this is true?)